# rewrite_rule() not preserving the query string

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

We have added a custom rewrite_rule to our site to allow for a pretty inbound link to be parsed and handled properly.  Links are constructed as `domain.com/meetings/faculty/someIDnumber`

```
add_action( "init", "pleasing_permalinks" );
function pleasing_permalinks() {
    add_rewrite_tag( '%hash%', '([^&]+)' );
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'meetings/faculty/([^/]+)/?$',
        'index.php?p=1598&hash=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
    //flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

[Rewrite Analyzer](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/) approves of the above but when we test with actual links in the browser, the embedded ID number is not preserved.  What are we missing here?

Comment: +1 for commenting out the flush_rewrite_rules, massive performance drop on 'init'

Comment: are you testing `domain.com/faculty/someIDnumber` instead of `domain.com/meetings/faculty/someIDnumber` ?

Comment: No, sorry. That's a speed-typing omission.  We are testing the correct paths.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `faculty` is a child page of `meetings`, the rule should be:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    'meetings/faculty/([^/]+)/?$',
    'index.php?pagename=meetings/faculty&hash=$matches[1]',
    'top'
);
```

`pagename=meetings/faculty` instead of `p=1598`

EDIT- or alternately:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    'meetings/faculty/([^/]+)/?$',
    'index.php?page_id=1598&hash=$matches[1]',
    'top'
);
```

`page_id=1598` instead of `p=1598`

Comment: 1598 is the page ID in question.  Are you saying that we cannot use the direct ID as index.php?p=XXXX in the rewrite?

Comment: you can't use `p=` for a page, use either the path or `page_id=`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the first index rather than the second?

```
'index.php?p=1598&hash=$matches[0]',
```

Arrays in PHP start at 0 not 1

Comment: <slowly and repeatedly slams head into desk>.  I hope that isn't it.  That's too easy

Comment: That's not it.  According to the Codex (http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) "NOTE: When using $matches[] to retrieve the values of a matched URL, capture group data starts at 1, not 0."

Answer (score 0):

Just tested your code on a clean WP installation and was able to get the variable with:

```
echo $wp_query->query_vars['hash'];
```

> Wordpress Codex - [add_rewrite_tag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag):
>   Note that using $_GET on a rewritten URL will not work, even if the
>   rewrite includes the querystring variables. You must use $wp_query.

Edit: As written in the correct answer 'p' must be replaced with 'page_id' to be able to keep the variables when redirecting to a post of type 'page'.

Comment: the issue was that WordPress will redirect and strip the extra parameter from the URL if your rule doesn't point to a valid object, in this case `p=` assumes the `post` post type while the desired post was of type `page`. it's not a matter of how to access the query var if you're redirected to a URI that no longer contains that query var.

Comment: Ah I see. I didn't understand the problem then. Thx for clearing that up!